# SQL table and relation design

Tags: sql, database-design

I have the following three tables

```
         Deliveries
DeliveryID   A1    
-----------|----|
1          | 01 |      
2          | 01 |      
3          | 02 | 

         JobLinks
LinkID  DeliveryID   A1   JobID
------|------------|-----|------|  
1     | Null       | 01  |  1   |
2     | 3          | Null|  2   |

          Jobs
 JobID   
-------|
1      |      
2      |
```

So the knowledge gained by this is that Job 1 is for Deliveries 1 and 2, and Job 2 is for Delivery 3.

A query that demonstrates this,

```
SELECT  Deliveries.DeliveryID,
        Jobs.JobID
FROM    Deliveries
        JOIN JobLinks 
            ON JobLinks.DeliveryID = Deliveries.DeliveryID
            OR JobLinks.A1 = Deliveries.A1
        JOIN Jobs
            ON Jobs.JobID = JobLinks.JobID
```

This will return each delivery and its associated Job

```
DeliveryID  JobID    
-----------|-----|
1          | 1   |      
2          | 1   |      
3          | 2   |
```

The problem that I see is that Deliveries.A1 is not a Unique field. It can be changed after the Delivery record has been created. Which would mean I would potentially have to update the JobLinks table whenever this field is changed. This seems like a bad design to me. How can I design these relationships to avoid this?

Comment: You could put a trigger on Deliveries so that anytime A1 is updated in Deliveries, it gets similarly updated in JobLinks.

Comment: Is it a good idea to use triggers to maintain table relationships? I feel like performance may degrade as these tables get larger and larger. I can easily redesign the relationship structure.

Comment: To me, it appears the deliveries table can be removed if delivery_id and A1 are no longer nullable. If there is more information contained in the deliveries table (that isn't visible), then eliminate the A1 field in the JobLinks table and make sure the delivery_id is no longer nullable. If the A1 changes in either case, you only have to change it in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a table for A1 metadata with and `ID` autonumeric

```
A1_ID    A1_meta
  1      01
  2      02
```

Then `Deliveries` and `JobLinks` will referece `A1_ID` as Foreign Key

So you only change `A1_meta` in one place

Comment: I like this. However, what if the user only wants to change A1 for one of the Deliveries, not all of them with matching A1

Comment: A1_meta or A1_ID ? Anyway that probably will be better ask as a new question because will need some sample data and desire output.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, i don't know what is your needs, but this is definitely bad design.

Comment: If you don't know how to solve it, don't post an answer, it just clutters up space.